# Identification d'un patois

Tags: jeux, dialectes

Le texte suivant est en « patois ». Il provient du jeu vidéo [Breath of Fire III sur PlayStation](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/196817-breath-of-fire-iii) qui a reçu une traduction française de qualité exécrable, basée elle même sur une médiocre traduction en anglais de l'original qui était en japonais.

Le personnage qui dit ce texte parle probablement dans le dialecte d'Osaka ou quelque chose du genre, ce qui a été traduit en « australien » pour la version en anglais, puis en « patois » pour la version en français.

> Boudiou ! Z'étions t-y point torés ? C'est quoué qu'vous m'frappions comme çé ? J't'ions eulemin gentil cause que les ptiots tions lo ! E n'les aurions point ménagés si zétiez tiou seuls. Et bin c'te phare. Quand l'étions brillant j'avions el'jaune din ma trinche et j'pouvions point dormir ! Tin moué ça, hein ! Ot'min j'vons changer e d'ton, tin compris ?!

Mes questions sont :

**1. Est-ce du vrai patois ou est-ce simplement une imitation?**

**2. Si c'est un vrai patois, duquel s'agit-il ?**

*EDIT: Afin que ce soit clair une fois pour toutes, je ne demande **pas** une traduction ou une aide quelconque quant à la compréhension de ce texte.*

[Voir la scène du jeu en anglais sur youtube](https://youtu.be/OA62q1STU4A?t=133)

Comment: Je mets ceci en commentaire plutôt qu'en réponse car je ne sais pas s'il s'agit d'un dialecte ayant son propre nom. Cela ressemble davantage selon moi à une imitation de parler « paysan ». Un ami m'a une fois dit que pour imiter ce type de parler, il suffisait de remplacer les conjugaisons présent + première personne du singulier par imparfait + première personne du pluriel, un mécanisme que l'on observe dans ton extrait.

Comment: @Chop Oui, je soupçonne que ce n'est qu'une imitation, mais je ne sais pas comment pouvoir le vérifier

Comment: Pour moi aussi, commentaire qui ne se prétend pas "réponse", pour une simple remarque. Ca me donne vraiment l'impression d'être une pure construction de fantaisie, à l'aide de "morceaux" glanés ici et là, justement parce que certains d'entre eux semblent pouvoir être "localisés" avec certitude, alors même que ces localisations sont contradictoires. Je pense à : **Boudiou**, déjà épinglé ci-dessous comme clairement du sud ; la combinaison (également déjà épinglée) 1ère personne du pluriel + imparfait, plutôt du centre ou de l'ouest ; enfin ces tournures parfaitement "ch'ti" : suite ci-dessous..

Comment: "el'jaune din ma trinche" ; "Ot'min" ; "changer e d'ton, tin compris ?". Mais justement, entre ces deux dernières citations, le "j'vons" ne colle pas avec du ch'ti, qui devrait être "j'vin". De même que les "qoué" ou "moué" ne peuvent pas être ch'ti. Donc je le répète, pour moi, construction de toutes pièces (mélangées, les pièces !).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Au sujet des verbes uniquement: l'emploi de verbes conjugués à la première personne du pluriel avec des pronoms autres que *nous*. C'est souvent en littérature mis dans la bouche de personnages d'origine paysanne. Par exemple, comme on l'[indique](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NapPTdcVgzkC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&ots=zMhe0q51YD&focus=viewport&dq=parler%20paysan%20moli%C3%A8re%20-ions&hl=fr), chez *Molière* dans le [Dom Juan](http://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dom_Juan_ou_le_Festin_de_pierre_%28Imprimerie_nationale%29#ACTE_II) :

> [*Pierrot*, paysan] Aga, guien, Charlotte, je m’en vas te conter tout fin drait comme cela
>   est venu ; car, comme dit l’autre, je les ai le premier avisés, avisés
>   le premier je les ai. Enfin donc **j’estions** sur le bord de la mar, moi
>   et le gros Lucas, et je nous **amusions** à batifoler avec des mottes de
>   tarre que je nous **jesquions** à la teste ; car, comme tu sais bian, le
>   gros Lucas aime à batifoler, et moi par fouas je batifole itou. En
>   batifolant donc, pisque batifoler y a, j’ai aperçu de tout loin
>   queuque chose qui grouillait dans gliau, et qui venait comme envars
>   nous par secousse.[...]
>
> [ Molière, *Dom Juan*, Acte I, Scène II, [1682](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dom_Juan_ou_le_Festin_de_pierre) ]

*Je* avec un verbe à la première personne du pluriel est un emploi ancien qui est [documenté](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/je?idf=dmfXgXrmXjdj;str=0) (*Je ly avons baillé la mitre*. [!] (*Pass. Semur* D.M., c.1420 [1488], 152). - *DmF*).

---

En Amérique ce genre d'emploi des verbes rappelle parfois le [*Français Acadien*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien). Le [document](https://books.google.ca/books?id=c-MNAAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA89&ots=6GB3NC_Ap3&dq=acadian%20verbs%20j%27avions&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=acadian%20verbs%20j%27avions&f=false) suivant au sujet du [*Français Cadien*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_cadien) (sud des États-Unis; voir aussi [*Cajun French*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajun_French)) contient une lettre dont voici un extrait où on utilise surtout il/ils avec le verbe à la première personne du pluriel :

> D'abord l'public s'a intéressé a connaite notre histoire, mouan j'va
>   dire tout ça j'connais et pi les autres vont conter ça ils savions.
>   Pou ça je connais, j'ai toujours attendu dire que les premiers Cadiens
>   qu'a venu icite étions arrivés du Nord par le Missippi. Ils venions
>   des Illinoués et s'étions éparpillés tout le long du fleuve et ceuze
>   qu'a quitté la grand bande avions arrêté côté nous autres. Ils étions
>   tous des chasseurs et des coureurs des bois. La beauté des
>   chauvagesses les avions tenté: ça fait y en a plein dans eux autres
>   qui s'avions marié avec ces filles des bois. Mouan j'en connais plein
>   des familles icite qu'a du sang chauvage et même qu'ils étions bien
>   fiers de descendre des premiers habitants: i s'disions les seuls vrais
>   Américains. Pour lors donc eune fois établis icite, tous ces
>   gaillards-là s'avions mis à travailler dur; et pi i s'étions bâti des
>   cabanes pi avions défréchi et netteyé d'la terre et chacun dans eux
>   autres a eu eune désert pou cultiver du maïs, du tabac, de l'indigo,
>   et boucoup plus tard du coton et pi ensuite a venu la canne et ensuite
>   le riz.
>
> [ M. Batis Grosboeuf, lettre écrite de [Bayou Choupique](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bayou_St._John), le 15
>   novembre 1890, ds.  « *The Acadians of Louisiana and their dialect* », Alcée Fortier dans *Publications of the Modern Language Association of America*, Volume 6, 1891 ]

Answer (score 1):

Ceci pourrait s'approcher d'un véritable dialecte. Les [langues d'oïl](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_d%27o%C3%AFl#Aper.C3.A7u_des_langues_d.27o.C3.AFl_modernes) comprennent plusieurs variantes qui ressemblent à ce genre de chose.

Reste à savoir de quelle langue d'oïl il pourrait s'agir et à déterminer si l'orthographe et la grammaire utilisées sont bien fidèles.

On trouve des traces de « toré » dans un [patois ardennais](https://books.google.lu/books?id=BG6DurBCCJQC&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=patois+tor%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=grzscZ90Sg&sig=3Kcoh7xDWHJqg7pUClCVKalhXZ0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R3lIVcSEEsqBabjsgfgE&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA), mais le sens m'est incertain. Il est présent dans d'autres dialectes avec le sens de « taureau », qui n'est pas celui utilisé ici.

« Eulemin » en revanche n'est pas indexé par Google autrement que sous forme de prénom.

Comment: En fait la version en français du jeu est truffé d'erreurs comme par exemple des lettres qui manquent, des phrases dont le début ou la fin manquent, le texte qui sort de l'écran, etc... Il est donc bien possible que ce genre d'erreurs aient été introduites dans le passage en "patois", comme dans "eulemin"

Comment: Ici j'imagine que "toré" signifie "taré".

Comment: J'ai la même traduction en tête. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Est-ce du vrai patois ou est-ce simplement une imitation?

Il s'agit très vraisemblablement d'un « pseudo patois » inventé pour l'occasion. En particulier *Boudiou* est typiquement occitan alors que les autres phrases sont inspirées des parlers d'oïl.

Boudiou !

> Bon Dieu !

Z'étions t-y point torés ?

> N'êtes-vous pas tarés ?

C'est quoué qu'vous m'frappions comme çé ?

> C'est quoi que vous (me) frappez comme ça ?

J't'ions eulemin gentil cause que les ptiots tions lo !

> J'étais seulement gentil à cause des petits, tiens là !

ou

> J'étais seulement gentil à cause que les petits étaient là !

E n'les aurions point ménagés si zétiez tiou seuls.

> Et je ne les aurais pas ménagés s'ils avaient été tous seuls.

Et bin c'te phare. Quand l'étions brillant j'avions el'jaune din ma trinche et j'pouvions point dormir !

> Et bien ce phare. Quand il était brillant, j'avais le jaune dans ma tronche et je ne pouvais pas dormir !

Tin moué ça, hein !

> Tiens-moi ça, hein !

Ot'min j'vons changer e d'ton, tin compris ?!

> Autrement, je vais changer de ton, tu as compris ?!

Comment: As tu lu ma question? Je ne demande pas une traduction (d'ailleurs il y en a une dans le jeu)

Comment: J'ai bien lu la question mais je n'ai pas vu de traduction ni même entendu le dialogue original dans le lien fourni. Seulement des sous titres en anglais, le bruit des vagues et d'une arme automatique.

Comment: 1. Il n'y a rien à "entendre" 2. L'original est en japonais 3.Lis la question s.t.p.

Comment: Il n'y a pas de dialogue en Japonais non plus, et les sous titres ne correspondent pas au texte posté (ou je n'ai pas été assez patient). S'il y a une traduction déjà fournie, pourquoi ne pas la mettre dans la question initiale ? Et pourquoi alors te poser la question de la signification de "toré" ou "eulemin" ??

Comment: Je traduirais plutôt "J't'ions eulemin gentil cause que les ptiots tions lo !" par "Je n'étais gentil que parce que les petits étaient là" ("tions lo" correspondant alors à "étions là" et donc à "étaient là" plutôt qu'à "tiens, là").

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Oui, j'ai hésité entre les deux et choisi cette version qui parait moins en contradiction avec la phrase suivante. Ce serait plus simple si on avait une version anglaise (australienne ?) à se mettre sous la dent ...

Comment: @jlliagre Je n'ai jamais posé la question de la signification de ce texte. Sinon j'abandonne, c'est inutile de continuer d'argumenter à ce stade là.

Comment: J'ai répondu à la question posée. Si ma réponse ne te conviens pas, c'est ton choix, pas de problème.

Comment: Ah oui tu as rajouté une réponse au début, merci! Donc oui, il est prouvé que c'est une sorte de mixture de patois réels? Intéressant.