# « Je ly avons baillé la mitre » ?

Tags: sens, religion, ancien-français

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13773), on nous présente l'emploi inusité et ancien du pronom *je* avec un verbe à la première personne du pluriel :

> -Je + verbe à la 1e pers. du plur. : *[Je](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/je?idf=dmfXgXrmXjdj;str=0) ly avons [baillé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/bailler1?idf=dmfXdXpcYbb;str=0) la [mitre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/mitre1?idf=dmfXgXrmXmghe;str=0)*. (*Pass. Semur D.M.*, c.1420 [1488], 152).
>
> [ [DmF](http://www.atilf.fr/dmf/) - *Dictionnaire du Moyen Français* (1330-1500) ]

Dans la [*Passion bourguignonne de Semur*](http://data.bnf.fr/12008394/passion_de_semur/) (« Mystère en 2 journées composé en Bourgogne au XVe s., s'inspirant de la Passion de Sainte-Geneviève »), on retrouve l'extrait particulier dans le quatrain [suivant](https://archive.org/stream/lemystredelapa01roy#page/110/mode/2up/search/mitre) :

> [Vivant]
>  Par le grant Dieu, ce faison mon,
>  Mes mieulx
>   choisir l'on ne pourroi,
>  Sur tous autres estre le doit.
>  *Je ly
>   avons baillé la mitre*.
>
> [ *Le mystère de la Passion en France du XIVe au XVIe siècle : étude
>   sur les sources et le classement des mystères de la Passion ;
>   accompagnée de textes inédits: [...] La Passion de Semur*,[...], 1904
>   ]

De quoi parle-t-on dans la strophe et que dit-on exactement dans la dernière phrase en particulier (quel sens de *bailler/mitre*, et "lui" quoi/qui/où/de quoi) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cette strophe relate l'ordination d'une personne dans le français du XVème siècle (une explication de la cérémonie apparemment de cette époque [ici](https://books.google.lu/books?id=kFGNHiIUSC0C&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=baill%C3%A9+la+mitre&source=bl&ots=HqESmYr7i0&sig=MIsnUIpzmBvVTAJ4r8Khi-gK7t0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cv1KVY_NF4rkUqaYgbAB&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=baill%C3%A9%20la%20mitre&f=false)).

« Bailler » a ici une [définition désuette](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bailler) au sens de « donner » et la [mitre](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitre) désigne aujourd'hui la coiffe des évêques.

Il n'y avait bien sûr pas encore d'évêques lors de la passion du Christ, il faudrait donc une analyse plus détaillée du texte complet pour comprendre de qui il s'agit (le Christ ou un apôtre ?).

Ci-dessous, une tentative de réécriture dans un français plus moderne. Les passages ou tournures non adaptées sont en italique et la réponse est en mode wiki pour que chacun puisse corriger.

> Par le grand Dieu, le faisant mien,
>   Mais mieux choisir l'on ne pourrait,
>   Au dessus de tous les autres, être, le doit.
>   Je lui ai remis la mitre.

Comment: Je souhaitais simplement que chacun puisse compléter la version en français contemporain mais je prends en compte tes remarques afin d'utiliser cette fonctionnalité à meilleur escient à l'avenir. Merci.

Comment: Je comprends et j'apprécie. Merci!