# What is «quement»?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, littérature, ancien-français

I was reading Dom Juan of Moliere and I found very hard to understand the first scene of the second act. I found words like «queuque» , «queu» and «toujou», but perhaps the strangest one was «quement», which I could not find in dictionaries and I am wondering if you know what it means. Here is the text:

«PIERROT

O acoute un peu auparavant, Charlote, j'ay queuque autre chose à te dire, moy.

CHARLOTE

Et bian, dy, qu'est-ce que c'est ?

PIERROT

Vois-tu, Charlote, il faut, comme dit l'autre, que je débonde mon coeur. Je taime, tu le sçais bian, et je
somme pour estre mariez ensemble, mais marquenne, je ne suis point satisfait de toy.

CHARLOTE

Quement ? qu'est-ce que c'est donc qu'iglia ?

PIERROT

Iglia que tu me chagraignes l'esprit franchement.

CHARLOTE

Et quement donc ?

PIERROT

Testiguienne, tu ne maimes point.

CHARLOTE

Ah, ah, n'est-ce que ça ?

PIERROT

Oüy, ce n'est que ça, et c'est bian assez.

CHARLOTE

Mon quieu, Piarrot, tu me viens toujou dire la mesme chose.

PIERROT

Je te dis toujou la mesme chose, parce que c'est toujou la mesme chose, et si ce n'estoit pas toujou la
mesme chose, je ne te dirois pas toujou la mesme chose.

CHARLOTE

Mais, qu'est-ce qu'il te faut ? que veux-tu ?

PIERROT

Jerniquenne, je veux que tu m'aimes.

CHARLOTE

Est-ce que je ne taime pas ?

PIERROT

Non, tu ne maimes pas, et si je fais tout ce que je pis pour ça. Je tachete, sans reproche, des rubans à tous
les Marciers qui passont, je me romps le cou à taller denicher des marles, je fais joüer pour toy les
Vielleux quand ce vient ta feste, et tout ça comme si je me frapois la teste contre un mur. Vois-tu, ça n'est
ny biau ny honneste de naimer pas les gens qui nous aimont».

Answer (score 8):

Quement = Comment.

Pierrot parle dans un patois d'Île de France.
Bien de ses mots et tournures sont aujourd'hui oubliées.
Je te suggère de lire cette scène ici : http://www.toutmoliere.net/acte-2,405392.html où tu trouveras les explications nécessaires en notes.

Et ici : https://www.persee.fr/doc/caief_0571-5865_1989_num_41_1_1700 pour découvrir l'intérêt et la mode de procéder ainsi pour un écrivain de l'époque.

Answer (score 3):

En ce qui a trait à *quement*, ça signifie ou marque *comment* et au lexique on en trouve des traces dans les « dialectes » ou anciennes langues françaises : au FEW à l'étymon [*quōmŏdo*](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/index.php/page/lire/e/59975) (comme) sous différentes graphies selon les régions (*quement, quément, quemment, qu'ment* etc.). Par ailleurs au [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) (début 20<sup>e</sup> Québec) on nous dit que c'était de même sens (comment) que ce qu'on retrouvait en Anjou, Berry, Maine, Nivernais, Normandie et Poitou...

Comment: Relativement à ton observation d'un autre coté de l'Atlantique... je rappellerai sans le moindre manque de respect mais, juste pour, dans le contexte de la littérature du XVIIe m'amuser à l'inverser en citant... : *Nos paysans sont un peu les Hurons du XVIIe.* ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt La citation fait également référence aux _Persans_ ; ce sont des [types sociaux](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13778) qui changent selon les époques et qui sont employés hier comme d'aujourd'hui ; le paysan est un stéréotype incontournable en effet mais la littérature n'est pas mon domaine. Je t'invite à extraire des liens que tu présentes les informations pertinentes pour éviter au lecteur d'avoir à chercher ; la note 1 du lien contient une liste qui ne contient pas _quement_ et ne permet de répondre à la question concernant ce mot précisément, d'où ma réponse. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

”Quement” (in ~16th century ) was today’s ”comment” = ”how” or ”how come” (keep in mind that ”how come” is an informal way to ask why or the reason why )

Toujou = toujours = always/all the time...