# Le pronom « je » avec le verbe conjugué à la première personne du pluriel : valeur, raison de l'emploi ?

Tags: pronoms, verbes, conjugaison, origine-ou-raison, dialectes

> « Ces [Québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_R%C3%A9giment_de_la_Chaudi%C3%A8re) parlaient le patois [normand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normand) de chez nous. Les pêcheurs
>   et les agriculteurs le parlaient. Alors on se comprenait. »  — Michel
>   Le Gallo, 82 ans, témoin du jour J, ds. [*Lapresse.com*](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/201906/01/01-5228452-debarquement-de-normandie-on-noublie-pas-ces-choses-la.php)

Par curiosité, je lis sur l'[influence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normand#Influence_dans_d'autres_pays) du normand (écouter [ici](https://atlas.limsi.fr/?tab=Hexagone)) sur la français [québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois) et [acadien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien) et dans ce dernier cas je lis dans l'article Wikipédia que « cependant, alors que quelqu'un parlant le [jersiais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersiais) dira *j'avons ieu*, un Acadien dira *j'avions eu* (**nous** avons eu) [...] ». J'ai toujours pensé qu'il s'agissait de la première personne du singulier et non de la première personne du pluriel, entre autres parce qu'un [exemple](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13778) dans la bouche de personnages chez Molière porte à confusion et qu'autrement j'ai toujours entendu ça à l'oral (sans marqueurs tels les participes passés au pluriel etc.). D'autre part je regarde la [conjugaison](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normand#Conjugaison) des verbes en normand et je trouve pour le verbe *avoir* : *j'(a)i, t'âs, il/ol a, **no-z-a**, **j'avoums**, vos avaez, il/ol ount.*

---

Quand le *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Boeck/Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>) présente l'emploi (« moderne », c'est-à-dire pour reproduire la langue populaire, surtout paysanne) , il dit « Je pour *nous* (ou *je* suivi de la 1ère pers. du plur.) » (LBU14 §659 g), laissant planer un doute dans mon esprit sur l'emploi possible avec valeur de première du singulier, puis donne des exemples et dans certains cas (mais pas tous) la valeur au pluriel est sans équivoque vu le reste de la phrase ou des indications :

> *M'sieur Bernard, j'venons chez vous parce que je n'osons pas aller
>   trouver M'sieur Achille* [...] *Nous, j'sommes toujours sacrifiées*
>   [disent des épinceteuses normandes] (Maurois, *Bernard Quesnay*)
>   *Je regardions la mer au loin tous les deux.* (A. Maillet, *Sagouine*)

Il ajoute que l'emploi en français [apparaît](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/je?idf=dmfXrmXmotsgrammaticauxXbda;str=0) au 15<sup>e</sup> et qu'au 16<sup>e</sup> on le trouve dans toutes les classes sociales (« [J'avons espérance qu'il fera beau temps](https://www.littre.org/definition/je) », François 1<sup>er</sup>) avant de le voir réservé par les auteurs aux « gens du peuple » ; on termine en disant que l'emploi « est assez général dans les dialectes d'[oïl](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langue_d%27o%C3%AFl), picard exclu » (LBU14, §659 note H8).

---

- Peut-on confirmer que dans toutes les variétés et tous les parlers du français le pronom *je* avec le verbe conjugué à la première du pluriel a **systématiquement** la valeur du *nous*/1<sup>ère</sup> du pluriel du verbe ?
- D'où provient et pourquoi trouve-t-on cet emploi, et la concurrence entre les pronoms [*je*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/je) et [*nous*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/nous) le cas échéant, pour la première personne du pluriel du verbe en français, et pourquoi aussi « tardivement » (du 15 <sup>e</sup> au 16<sup>e</sup>) ?

Comment: Juste une ébauche d'hypothèse, donc je me limite à un message plutôt qu'à une réponse: Les pronoms sujets ils et elles sont des innovations récentes du Francien, et la plupart des autres langues gallo-romanes ont conservé les pronoms directement issus de illi et illae: il et elle. Couplé avec une tendance pour les formes polies en vous de supplanter celles en tu, et une terminaison de la troisième personne du pluriel en -ont par analogie avec sont, ont, vont, etc. la plupart des langues d'oïl se sont retrouvée avec un paradigme verbal similaire à celui du wallon de bastogne moderne (cont.)

Comment: À savoir: (verbe cognat de changer) dju tchandje, tu tchindjes, i tchindje, dju tchindjans, vos tchindjoz, i tchindjant, avec des suffixes verbaux nuls au singulier et des suffixes de la première et de la troisième personnes du pluriel identiques. Par analogie avec des paires comme il avance (singulier) il avançont (pluriel), la première personne serait passé de j'avance / nous avançons à  j'avance / j'avonçons. (cont.)

Comment: En soutien à cette hypothèse, les deux principales variétés d'oil qui ont conservé "nos" comme pronom de la 1ère personne du pluriel (le wallon et le picard) ont des suffixes distincts pour les 1ère et 3ème personnes du pluriel: picard os parlons - il parl'te, wallon de Charleroi nos cåzons, i cåzneut

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La première question revient malheureusement à prouver un négatif. C'est d'autant plus compliqué que les attestations de je -ons avec un référent singulier sont rares, peuvent être le résultat d'une mauvais imitation de la forme populaire par quelqu'un dont elle ne fait pas partie du dialecte, ou d'une réinterprétation de l'ancien système par un néo-locuteur d'une langue régionale qu'ils n'ont que partiellement maîtrisée.

Voici ce qu'une note de bas de page tirée de KING Ruth et al., "The interplay of internal and external factors in grammatical change: First-person plural pronouns in French" (une étude de corpus de textes littéraire étudiant les changements de pronouns de la 1PP en français) a à dire sur ce sujet :

> Use of je + verb + -ons with a singular reference—that is, meaning
> ‘I’—occurs with varying levels of frequency in our literary corpora,
> and in most instances such use coexists with use of the same form but
> with a first-person plural reference. Lodge (2004) has also found
> instances of such mixed usage in his corpus of representations of
> seventeenth- and eighteenth-century lower-class Parisian French. One
> can find two attestations of je + verb + -ons with a singular
> reference in the Atlas linguistique de la france (locations #153 and #246,
> for map 975). Morin (p.c.) suggests that the rarity of such forms may be a
> reflection of a misinterpretation of the question posed
> by the fieldworker. First-person singular reference has also been
> noted for the nineteenth and twentieth centuries by Berthier (1996),
> Chaurand (1968), Deguillaume (1998), and Moisy (1887), although it is
> not clear whether it involves reanalysis of an older system.

Le je pluriel est né vers la fin de l'ancien français, durant une période où l'on a vu apparaître, partout ou régionalement selon les cas, des usages où le pronom et l'inflexion verbale ne s'accordaient pas. Gaston Zink, dans sa thèse de 1981 sur la Morphosyntaxe du pronom personnel en Moyen Français, en décrit de plusieurs types : j'avons, tu seriès (=tu seriez), on avons, on ont, nous a, qu'il attribue "à l'aptitude des pronoms pluriel [..] et de [...] on à s'identifier (au niveau du discours [...]) à ceux qu'ils incorporent or qui les incorporent". En d'autres termes, l'usage discursif, ou poli, des pronoms pluriels, pour des référents singuliers ou indéfinis aurait dissocié leur sens de la stricte références à une personne grammaticale précise et aurait permis leur usage de plus en plus fréquent en référence à d'autres personnes grammaticales. Je ne suis personnellement pas tout à fait convaincu (ces usages sont présents également en français moderne sans produire les mêmes effets), mais Zink est le seul à fournir une explication au phénomène que j'aie pu trouver dans la littérature.

Reste à expliquer pourquoi de ces divers usages seul le je pluriel s'est imposé dans le parler populaire en français comme dans les autres langues d'oïl en moyen français, au point de rester bien implanté dans les usages européens jusqu'à l'instauration de la scolarité obligatoire, malgré les foudres des premiers grammairiens. (Vu sa popularité en Europe, c'est sans surprise que le je pluriel se retrouve dans la koinè canadienne et qu'il survit dans les français des Amériques jusqu'à nos jours)

Dans les langues locales européennes, le je pluriel est hégémonique dans la région d'oïl, sauf dans le Nord-Est et en Franco-Provençal où le nous reste le pronom usuel de la 1ère personne comme l'indique les cartes de l'ALF ([0027 nous allons](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/visualiseur?nomCarte=0027), [0100 que nous ayons](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/visualiseur?nomCarte=0100), [0318 nous connaissons](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/visualiseur?nomCarte=0318), pour n'en citer que quelques unes).

[image]

Source: [Mathieu Avanzi](https://twitter.com/MathieuAvanzi/status/1233027945192730624)

Une raison potentielle pour cette persistance du je pluriel est le parallélisme avec la 3ème personne : L'Ancien Français utilisait il comme pronom de la 3ème personne masculine au singulier comme au pluriel, une évolution naturelle des pronoms latin *ille* et *illī* qui n'avaient aucun /s/. Au féminin, elle et elles existent tous les deux, la terminaison du -æ du nominatif pluriel ayant très tôt été remplacée par -as (elle semble donc être un archaïsme de la déclinaison pronominale). Ils est une innovation du Moyen Français qui n'a jamais totalement pénétré dans les autres langues gallo-romanes ([carte ALF 0093 quand elles ont](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect3/visualiseur?nomCarte=0093)).

De plus, le suffixe de la troisième personne du pluriel a connu plusieurs variations, qu'on peut schématiser en trois grand groupes :

- Le type français des classes supérieures, où le suffixe atone -ent persiste mais se réduit progressivement à un simple /ə(t)/, identique aux suffixes du singulier hors des contextes de liaison
- Le type d'oïl (y compris le français populaire), où le suffixe tonique -ont est emprunté à plusieurs verbes irréguliers (sont, font, vont) et généralisé à tous les verbes
- Le type wallon et picard, où le suffixe atone -ent est renforcé par une voyelle d'appui qui le protège de la perte des consonnes finales (picard /-t/, /-tə/) voire attire l'accent et devient la source d'un nouveau suffixe tonique (wallon /-ny/, /-nø/, /-nɛ/)

Dans les langues du type 1 et 3, les 1ère et 3ème personnes du pluriel restent bien distinctes une fois les consonnes finales tombées, sauf bien sûr au futur :

- Français nous mangeons /mãʒõs -> mɑ̃ʒɔ̃/, il(s) mangent /mãʒət -> mɑ̃ʒə/
- Français nous mangions /mãʒjõs -> mɑ̃ʒjɔ̃/, il(s) mangeoient /mɑ̃ʒwɛət -> mɑ̃ʒwɛə/
- Wallon (Charleroi) nos mindjons /mẽdʒõs -> mẽdʒõ/, i mindjneut /'mẽ.dʒən.tə -> 'mẽ.dʒən.nə -> mẽ.dʒən.'nə -> mẽdʒ.'nø/
- Picard (Mons) nos mindjimes /mẽdʒiməs -> mẽdʒimə -> mindʒim/, i mindjin'te /mẽdʒiəntə -> mẽdʒiəntə -> mẽdʒintə/

Dans les langues de type 2 par contre, les suffixes -ons et -ont sont devenus homophones. La distinction entre les personnes est donc retombée sur les pronoms sujets, tandis que le nombre restait indiqué par les suffixes (exemple en français populaire):

> je mange /ʒə=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 1P=mange-SING
>
> tu manges /ty=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 2P=mange-SING
>
> il mange /i=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 3P=mange-SING
>
> nous mangeons /nu=mɑ̃ʒ-ɔ̃/ 1P.PL=mange-PL
>
> vous mangez /vu=mɑ̃ʒ-e/ 2P.PL=mange-2P.PL
>
> il mangeont /i=mɑ̃ʒ-ɔ̃/ 3P=mange-PL

Dans un tel système, généraliser *je* à la 1ère personne du pluriel aurait harmonisé d'avantage le paradigme, avec un pronom marquant la personne et un suffixe marquant le nombre. Une évolution semblable pour la seconde personne aurait été bloquée par l'usage de l'opposition entre tu et vous pour marquer la politesse.

> je mange /ʒə=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 1P=mange-SING
>
> tu manges /ty=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 2P=mange-SING
>
> il mange /i=mɑ̃ʒ-ə/ 3P=mange-SING
>
> **je mangeons /ʒə=mɑ̃ʒ-ɔ̃/ 1P=mange-PL**
>
> vous mangez /vu=mɑ̃ʒ-e/ 2P.PL=mange-2P.PL
>
> il mangeont /i=mɑ̃ʒ-ɔ̃/ 3P=mange-PL

Cela permettrait d'expliquer pourquoi les langues d'oïl qui utilisent le je pluriel et celles qui ont la même consonne nasale pour les suffixes des 1ère et 3ème personnes du pluriel coïncident.

De même en Amérique du Nord, les dialectes du français qui préservent le je pluriel, comme l'acadien, sont aussi ceux qui préservent -ont comme suffixe de la 3ème personne du pluriel : j'mangeons, i' mangeont.

Comment: Ça mériterait une relecture et des corrections, mais écrire tout ça m'a pris plusieurs jour et m'a épuisé, donc je le laisse pour plus tard

Answer (score 3):

En passant, lorsque j'étais petit et que je passais mes vacances sur l'île d'Oléron, je pouvais entendre les plus âgés utiliser parfois la conjugaison à la première personne du pluriel pour un pronom à la première du singulier. On pouvait donc encore trouver trace de cet usage dans les campagnes françaises dans les années 1980.

Le plus beau étant que cela pouvait être agrémenté d'une négation n'en ayant pas le sens. Ainsi, *j'avais* pouvait se transformer en *J'n'avions*.