# (Il) faut que je pars (paːʁ) : nouvelle tendance ?

Tags: subjonctif, oral

J'ai entendu, pas mal de fois, des personnes dire :

> (Il) faut que je pars

au lieu de

> (il) faut que je parte

Je suis sûr d'avoir entendu paːʁ et pas paːʁt. Est-ce qu'une nouvelle tendance ? Est-ce que les règles pour l'application du subjonctif à l'oral relâché deviennent moins strictes ?

Comment: C'est peut-être une tendance locale. En ce qui me concerne, "(Il) faut que je pars" me fait  mal aux yeux et aux oreilles ;)

Comment: Effectivement, certaines personnes le disent, mais que je sache, la conjugaison n'a pas changé. Les différences que l'on a entre l'écrit et l'oral en français me surprendront toujours... Après, la tendance à tout vouloir raccourcir à l'oral se fait de plus en plus, mais je ne pense pas qu'à terme, les changements persisteront

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, on entend de plus en plus l'indicatif au lieu du subjonctif après *il faut que*.

Il peut même arriver de le lire :

> *[Il faut que tu viens avec moi.](https://www.fanfic-fr.net/fanfics/imprimer/Livres-Romans/H/Harry-Potter/S%C3%A9phora-Harry/77332/358600.html)*

C'est du français très relâché, stigmatisé et condamné aujourd'hui par la norme.

Voici une référence qui décrit cette évolution :

> *Une « tendance » à l’amenuisement du subjonctif est observée par de nombreux auteurs dans plusieurs variétés de français. L’alternance du subjonctif et de l’indicatif dans des subordonnées est en réalité une donnée du français attestée depuis le XVIe siècle, toujours accompagnée des injonctions normatives visant à stabiliser la distribution des usages (Fournier 1998 : 331–373). Le subjonctif en subordonnée exclut l’assertion du locuteur ; il focalise l’attention sur le procès exprimé sans qu’il soit tenu compte de sa réalité. La pertinence de cette valeur modale, cependant, ne va pas toujours de soi puisque le subjonctif en tant que forme marquée n’existe pas pour de nombreux verbes. Par ailleurs, dans les usages, des études ont montré (surtout pour le français acadien (Chauveau (1998), Neumann-Holzschuh (2004), parmi d’autres), selon les contextes, soit une fluctuation imprévisible entre subjonctif et indicatif (après falloir, vouloir, pour que, avant que …), soit une absence du subjonctif (après jusqu’à ce que, il arrive que …). Chauveau (1998) rapproche ces faits de la tendance identique attestée de longue date en Bretagne, tendance correspondant elle-même au fonctionnement du breton où l’indicatif présent et futur et le conditionnel (utilisé aussi pour les constructions hypothétiques) sont employés là où le français (standard) recourt au subjonctif. Neumann-Holzschuh (2004), dans son étude formelle et fonctionnelle du subjonctif en français acadien, et plus généralement en français d’Amérique du Nord, montre aussi un étiolement du subjonctif, et fait remonter le processus aux XVIe et XVIIe siècles, donc aux débuts du français sur le continent. Elle met en évidence une apparition concurrente des formes de l’indicatif présent, futur et imparfait, du conditionnel et du subjonctif présent, avec la perte de la valeur modale spécifique du subjonctif, surtout en Louisiane et à Terre-Neuve et, dans une moindre mesure, au Nouveau-Brunswick et en Nouvelle-Ecosse. En France, au Québec et en Afrique, les alternances du subjonctif et de l’indicatif et la diminution du subjonctif sont attestées aussi. Des données récentes de français parlé en entretiens et conversations comportent quelques absences de subjonctif après à moins que, falloir que, avoir peur que, jusqu’à ce que, malgré que …, mais ces faits restent marginaux.*
>
> Béatrice Akissi Boutin & Nathalie Rossi-Gensane, *[Quelle(s) diversité(s) pour la syntaxe ?](https://www.peterlang.com/view/9783035397833/17_Chapter8.xhtml)*, 2013

Une autre référence, qui montre que cette absence de subjonctif peut être un régionalisme (Bretagne) :

> Comme en breton, le mode subjonctif peut être remplacé par un temps au mode indicatif. Cependant, le breton utilise un temps morphologique futur ou conditionnel, mais pas présent comme ci-dessous.
>
> Je préfère **que tu vas** et que tu me donnes.
> 'Je préfère que tu y ailles (au distributeur) et que tu me donnes (l'argent)', Lorient [01/2017]

Source: [CNRS, Français de Basse-Bretagne](https://arbres.iker.cnrs.fr/index.php?title=Fran%C3%A7ais_de_Basse-Bretagne#modes)

Comment: Je n'ai encore jamais vu cela. Est-ce répandu en dehors de fan fictions ou autre récits sur internet?

Comment: @Sacha C'est extrêmement rare à l'écrit, bien sûr, mais ça s'entend assez souvent.

Comment: Les locuteurs du XXIIe siècle nous jugeront peut-être comme nous pouvons juger ceux du début du XXe et leur utilisation du subjonctif imparfait après tout, l'avenir nous le dira.
Merci de ces précisions.

Comment: Dans la traduction des chants marins (et donc bretons) on entend aussi « j'allons » pour *je vais*.

Comment: @Personne Oui, en pays gallo. C'est un autre phénomène et c'était beaucoup plus répandu, quasiment dans toute l'aire rurale de la langue d’oïl hors Picard et Wallon. Ça mériterait une question.

Comment: Ah, la question existe déjà: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/36683/le-pronom-je-avec-le-verbe-conjugu%c3%a9-%c3%a0-la-premi%c3%a8re-personne-du-pluriel-vale

Comment: @Personne Je viens d'y rajouter une carte prise là : https://twitter.com/MathieuAvanzi/status/1233027945192730624

Answer (score 2):

Non et non, la règle avec le tour impersonnel *il faut que* + proposition du verbe *falloir* est le subjonctif ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4356), [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/falloir)). C'est une difficulté d'écolier connue depuis [longtemps](https://www.icem-freinet.fr/archives/educ/75-76/4/6.pdf). La condition socio-économique (accès à l'éducation) a possiblement eu un impact chez certains [types](https://books.google.com/books?id=t_c4KMeROF0C&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=%22il%20faut%20que%20je%20pars%22&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=%22il%20faut%20que%22&f=false) de locuteurs historiquement (mon avis) ou il a pu s'agir de [régionalismes](https://books.google.ca/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=aS4RAQAAIAAJ&dq=T%C3%A9moignages%20sur%20la%20syntaxe%20du%20verbe%20dans%20quelques%20parlers%20fran%C3%A7ais%20de%20Belgique&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22il%20faut%20que%20je%20pars%22). La réaction à cette erreur témoigne de l'importance de l'acquis qui se révèle à l'évidence un indicateur d'une bonne maîtrise de la langue, voire un quasi-[schibboleth](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schibboleth). Ça signifie aussi que ça peut-être utile au dialogue dans la bouche de personnages quand on veut évoquer différentes réalités qui diffèrent de la « norme » etc.

Il se peut que bien des apprenants parlent français (ce qui en soi serait encourageant) sans avoir intégré le mode subjonctif tout court ou son emploi ici avec ce tour du verbe et c'est l'impression que j'ai en cherchant ça sur le Web. Il y a un certain nombre de lacunes impliquant le subjonctif, s'expliquant en partie par l'[homophonie](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4237) de certaines formes entre l'indicatif et le subjonctif présent. Avec le verbe *partir* ce n'est pas le cas, mais on se sera sans doute trop fié à la forme du singulier (*je/tu pars, il part*). Il vaut mieux informer que condamner.

Pour aller encore plus loin, on peut parler par exemple avec intérêt du tour *il s'agit que* (parfois avec répétition) où l'on a le choix de mode selon le sens, l'indicatif pour le constat et le subjonctif pour la chose à accomplir (le tour valant *il faut que* dans ce cas) (LBU14 §1127a, incluant les exemples suivants) !

> Moi ? Il ne s'agit pas de moi. Il s'agit que tu ES malheureuse
> (Sagan).
>  Il ne s'agit pas que vous ÉCRIVIEZ, il faut que vous
> alliez vous-même (Littré)

Answer (score -1):

Il s'agit clairement d'une faute de français caractéristique d'un usage "primitif" de la langue. Cette forme est totalement absente de la littérature, à moins qu'elle ne rapporte par citation les propos d'un personnage demeuré.